# vim edit java file inside jar package

Tags: vim, unzip

I use unzip and vim inside terminal try to edit a java file inside jar, but when I open it I got sth like this, so I am unable to edit it. Could anybody help to give any solutions? many thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Looks like compiled java code. You need a java decompiler

Comment: I want to change some java codes and recompile it, does that mean I need to decompile it first?

Comment: Yes you need to decompile code from JAR

Answer (score 0):

You need a decompiler to edit compiled JAVA files (in JAR). For vim/gvim you can follow [instructions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_a_Java_Class_File_using_a_decompiler)